# How is MDN for a first time Javascript learner - best alternatives?

Tags: javascript

As the title suggests, I've been getting into Javascript. I began with W3schools, but was told they're not all their search results suggest.

I have a fair amount of programming experience, so while it is not necessarily over my head, I do feel that without any practice problems or challenges it's hard to have the lessons stick. It feels more like a reference source than an instructional tutorial.

Thoughts and recommendations appreciated!

/e
I've seen other answers asking about Javascript tutorials, but the post I keep finding my way to is nearly 6 years old, and was edited 4 years ago. A lot can change in that amount of time, and from what I've gathered MDN has especially changed quite a bit since then.

Comment: [***Alternative Resources To Learn JS***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript) || [***Javascript Is Sexy***](http://javascriptissexy.com/how-to-learn-javascript-properly/)

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for JavaScript tutorials is off-topic here - StackOverflow is for actual code question. That other post is left on the site only for historic reference.

Comment: Sorry about that, I suppose I realized the conflict with bias etc, but based of the previous post assumed it was alright. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MDN is *the* resource for web development and there's tons of articles showing you how to do things, not just reference pages. Stick to it like glue. It isn't perfect in the literal sense, but it is the standard reference for most web developers.

Other useful resources include:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) to play with your javascript
[caniuse](https://caniuse.com) to see if your javascript will work across browsers (although usually the MDN is accurate in what you can and can't use)

and a new favorite of mine [regex101](https://regex101.com) for regular expressions.

also, search engines are always your friends with web development so use them as much as possible.

edit - sorry, connection crapped out and didn't notice links where broken